# Avro json decoder : ignore namespace

Tags: java, json, avro

i tried to use Apache Avro on project... and i've met some difficulties
avro serialization/ deserialization work like a charm ... but  i get decoder exceptions.. like unknown union  branch blah-blah-blah... in case incomming json does't contain namepsace record ...
e.g.

```
"user":{"demo.avro.User":{"age":1000...  //that's ok

"user":{"age":1000...  //org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch age
```

I cannot put object in default namespace... but it is important  to parse incoming json regardless it contains namespace node or not
Could you help me to fix it

Answer (score -3):

If you use JSON, why are you using Avro decoders? There are tons of JSON libraries which are designed to work with JSON: with Avro, the idea is to Avro's own compact format, and JSON is mostly used for debugging (i.e. you can expose Avro data as JSON if necessary).